# alternate way to achieve the LISTAGG() functionality by using query in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2, aggregate-functions, listagg

For ex: table 'A' have column and values as below

### Name

saram

dev

stalin

merlyn

expected result:
saram,dev,stalin,merlyn

without using the listagg().
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi - why don't you want to use LISTAGG?

Comment: What's your Db2 platform and version? Are you ok with [XMLAGG](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=functions-xmlagg)? Why is LISTAGG not suitable for you?

Comment: REASON FOR NOT USING LISTAGG: Column have record as below(have nearly 1500 rows,ecach node is row value and first one have <row> as prefix similarly </row>): <row><child_last_name>ELLIS</child_last_name> <child_first_name>OLIVER</child_first_name> <child_middle_name>ELENA </child_middle_name> <child_suffix_name></child_suffix_name> <child_petitioner_name> </child_petitioner_name> <user_input_conception_date> </user_input_conception_date> . . <user_input_reason_desc> </user_input_reason_desc></row> <row><child_last_name>ELLIS</child_last_name> . ...</user_input_reason_desc></row>

Comment: 1.) When I use the LISTAGG() it throws because it exceeds the max length of listagg. ERROR [54006] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0137N The length resulting from "LISTAGG" is greater than "10000". 2.) I tried to use the xmlagg but it throws (because root node problem). ERROR [2200M] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL16203N XML document input ended before all started tags were ended. Last tag started was "row". 3.) when I concatenate all the rows to column then output will be like <row><child....</row><row>......</row>. These are the reasonS to ask alternate solution for this.

Comment: OK - that's rather an important reason: that you are creating very long strings.
You should update your question to make that clear - as the example you give, where just 4 small values are being grouped together, could result in someone wasting time giving you a solution that won't work/perform with large datasets

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example with strings of up to 2 MB in length.
You may try even longer strings as well.

```
WITH TAB (STR) AS
(
VALUES 'saram', 'dev', 'stalin', 'merlyn'
)
SELECT SUBSTR (XMLSERIALIZE (XMLAGG (XMLTEXT (',' || STR)) AS CLOB (2M)), 2)
FROM TAB
```

Comment: query returns this error: Lookup Error - Value cannot be an empty collection.
Parameter name: columnReaders

Comment: This is not a Db2 error. You may run my query as is to check it. Edit your question with your actual query text.